# How can I relate an entity with itself via ManyToMany?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My entity "Documents" is related to different entities like for example "members", "products" or "projects" .

In my mySQL database this creates tables like:

```
documents_members
documents_products 
documents_projects
```

Now I tried to create a relation with manytomany from documents to documents. So I added documents manytomany and I expect this table in my database:

```
documents_documents
```

This is my approach:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DocumentsRepository")
 *
 */
class Documents {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("documents")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Products", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="products", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Groups("documents")
     */
    private $products;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projects", inversedBy="documents")
     * @Groups("documents")
     */
    private $projects;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Members", inversedBy="documents")
     * @Groups("documents")
     */
    private $members;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Documents", mappedBy="documents")
     */
    private $documents;

}
```

Comment: [Doctrine docs: many-to-many self-referencing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing).

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have both sides of the relationship mapped.

Each `document` links to several other documents, and many other `documents` may link to this one.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Many Documents link to many Documents.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Documents", inversedBy="linkedFromDocuments")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_links",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_origin", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_destination", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $linkedDocuments;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Documents", mappedBy="linkedDocuments")
 */
private $linkedFromDocuments;
```

This will create a table named `document_links`, with two columns: `link_origin` and `link_destination`. On each of these columns there will be a foreign key pointing back to `documents`.

Note that the relationship is bi-directional. So you may have `document#1` linked to `document#2`, and also `document#2` pointing to `document#1` (two distinct rows in the join table). Your application may want to account for that.

Comment: Is this possible to be created only via console?

Comment: php bin/console make:entity

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. BraveChef):
> Documents

 to stop adding fields):
>documents

Field type (enter ? to see all types) [string]:
> relation

Comment: No idea, but for more elaborate relationships you'll do better doing it by hand.

Comment: I get an error: `[Semantical Error] The annotation "@JoinColumn" in property App\Entity\Documents::$linkedDocuments was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?`

Comment: I checked, it looks correctly. But maybe I have to replace these values `documentLinks`, `link_origin`, `link_destination` ? I copied it from your example and do not know where I find the replacement in my code

Comment: those are the names of the table and table columns. compare your code against the latest revision of my answer. try to understand the code, not simply copy it. you should have no other references to $documents in the entity but the ones from the answer.

Comment: But I need also to add  `public function __construct() {$this->linkedFromDocuments = new ArrayCollection();` and `public function addLinkedFromDocument(Documents $linkedFromDocument): self`

Comment: That's up to you, that's not part of the mapping. The rest of the entity implementation is what you'll have to do. I've shown you how to map the entity, you'll have to walk the last few meters by yourself.